# How to pass initial hidden state to the lstm layer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I want to pass a custom initial states to the lstm output but I only have one hidden state so how can I pass a zeros initial state .

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

x = layers.Input((None,))
x = layers.Embedding(....)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
imp_vec = Dense()(x)
```

now I want to use imp_vec as a hidden initial state and pass it to the decoder lstm

```
out, states = layers.LSTM(...., return_state=True)(inputs, initial_state=[imp_vec])
```

this above code returns value error:,

```
ValueError: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=ListWrapper([InputSpec(shape=(None, 200), ndim=2)]); however `cell.state_size` is [10, 10]
```

I found out that lstm requires two states as initial states (i.e hidden_state, cell_state) right? but I only have a hidden state vector to pass it to the model so how can I initialize only hidden_state and make lstm to automatically initialize the other one with zeros ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An LSTM has two states but you're passing just a single input. Therefore there's a couple of options

### Option 1: Instead of `LSTM` use `GRU`

GRUs have only one state and `initial_state=imp_vec` will work fine.

### Option 2: Create two different states

Instead of a single `imp_vec`, create `imp_vec_1` and `imp_vec_2` and pass it as,

```
layers.LSTM(..)(..., initial_state=[imp_vec_1, imp_vec_2])
```

Remember that `LSTM` layer taks `h_state` and `c_state` in that order.

### Option 3: Make `c_state` zero

If you don't want to pass a `c_state` just pass a set of zeros.

```
zero_out = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.zeros_like(x))(imp_vec)
layers.LSTM(..)(..., initial_state=[imp_vec, zero_out])
```

Comment: @thushv86 thank you, I just have one doubt, what does `x` in `tf.zeros_like(x)` refers to? what should be the shape of it?

Comment: @user_12, so that's a trick to get a state full of zeros that has the exact same shape as `imp_vec`. Because both `h` and `c` states have the same size. And this is a nice way to do that as it allows this to work even when batch dimension is `None`.

Comment: If you see the architecture that I've given in my question, x is referred to flatten layer right? so if we use `tf.zeros_like(x)` wouldn't this be same shape of flatten layer? Also do you mean both `imp_vec`, and `zero_out` have same shape?

Comment: @user_12, this `x` is **not** referring to the `x` in your code. That's totally different. The `x` I have exists only within the scope of the lambda layer. So instead of `x` you can have `lambda y: tf.zeros_like(y)` it will work. It just defines a transformation for a given input. And as you can see, the input to the lambda layer is `imp_vec`.

Comment: I get it now, I overlooked the fact we are using a lambda layer. Sorry. Also, how about the shapes of imp_vec, zero_out are these both have same shapes?

Comment: Yup the exact same shape. LSTMs have the exact shape for both states

Comment: Sir, just one more doubt. What are the names of states? I mean when we pass `initial_state = [imp_vec, zero_out]` which is hidden state here and which is cell/carry state ?

Comment: The hidden state (`h`) is the first state and cell state (`c`) is the second.

Comment: Sir, in option 2 it was mentioned to create an another state. Is there a way to create a empty state with zeros/something and with custom shapes (i.e like need 32x32 like that)

Comment: @user_12 if you want an empty state with zeros, go with option 3. Option 2 is to be used if you want to set the hidden states using two different neural networks.

Comment: I tried to use the third option but `tf.zeros_like(x))(imp_vec)` here the shapes of `imp_vec(?, 256)` is not what the shape I require`(?, 64)` for the newly created zero tensor. How can I overcome this?

Comment: You cannot decide all the dimensions of the states, it has to be a [batch size, num units] sized tensor. It cannot be anything else.

Comment: No I'm manually checked the shapes. Here I require `?, 256` for hiddenstate and '?, 64` for cell state. I tried using both as `?, 256` but returned error saying it requires `?, 64` for cell state. So is there a way achieve it.